# is there a way to reference a text variable and use it to create a table later

Tags: r

For example, I have the code below:

```
dat_name = "first"
```

I would like to create a dataset named "first_box" and I would like to use `dat_name` already referenced above to do that. I would like to do something like:

```
'dat_name'_box <- 1
```

The code above throws an error. Can someone know how I can achieve what I trying to do.. that way I can reuse the code and not have to rename the dataframe let's say I would like to create something like "second_box" next.

Comment: I would strongly reconsider such an appriach. It's not very R-like. It would be better to keep related values in a named list. Then it's much easier to work with the data otherwise you have to bother with `get()` and `assign()` which can be very messy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Can i suggest you spend some time with [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/), that might help you rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`assign`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/assign).

```
dat_name = "first"
var_name = paste0(dat_name, "_box")
assign(var_name, 1)
```

Then you'll get:

```
print(first_box)
[1]  1
```